# Meteor Currency Exchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, meteor

I am stuck with trying to get currency exchange updated by using `select` tag and fetching the values with JQuery.

My original plan was to use `{{#if}}` that is from Meteor handlebars to do the logic. While using MongoDB to switch fields, when user clicks different option, it will automatically switch the currency field.

I am currently using a Meteor package called `theara:moneyjs`. Click [here](https://atmospherejs.com/theara/moneyjs), for package information.

Here is my current code that I have:

**HTML**

```
<template name="product_table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Currency
                    <select id="currency">
                        <option value="aud">AUS Dollar</option>
                        <option value="usd">US Dollar</option>
                        <option value="hkd">HK Dollar</option>
                    </select>     
        {{#each product}}
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{productPrice}}</td>
                    <!-- {{#if getEXR}} Does not work, since is not a boolean value
                        <td>{{productPrice}}</td>
                    {{/if}} -->
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Template.product_table.helpers({
    product: function() {
        return Products.find({}, {sort:{createdAt:-1}});
    },

    getEXR: function() {
        $(document).on('change', '#currency', function () {
            var getCurrency = $("#currency option:selected").val();

            if (getCurrency === "aud") {
            //I am not quite sure, how grab specific field values from MongoDB
                fx.convert(Products.find().productPrice()).from("USD").to("AUD");
            }

            else if (getCurrency === "usd") {
                fx.convert(Products.find().productPrice()).from("USD").to("USD");
            }

            else if (getCurrency === "hkd") {
                fx.convert(Products.find().productPrice()).from("USD").to("HKD");
            }
    }
)};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you publishing the data you need?  I assume as you're doing this on the client you need to get the data from the client side data store (minimongo) secondly you should be using events.  Have you done the intro to meteor tutorial?  https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app  Meteor is quite different in its approach and you're going to have a bad time approaching it like this.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yes I am publishing and subscribing my data. My publications are done on the server side, while by subscriptions is done on the client side, in the same JS file.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to return an individual value from your getEXR helper instead of a cursor. Plus your helper wasn't returning anything!

You also don't even need the boolean. Use a Session variable (or reactive var) instead. See below:

**HTML**

```
<template name="product_table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Currency
                    <select id="currency">
                        <option value="AUD">AUS Dollar</option>
                        <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
                        <option value="HKD">HK Dollar</option>
                    </select>     
        {{#each product}}
            {{> oneProduct}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</template>

<template name="oneProduct">
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>{{productName}}</td>
           <td>{{productPrice}}</td>
           <td>{{localPrice}}</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Template.product_table.helpers({
    product: function() {
        return Products.find({}, {sort:{createdAt:-1}});
    }  
)};

Template.product_table.events({
  'change #currency': function(ev){
      Session.set('currency') = $("#currency option:selected").val();
  }
});

Template.oneProduct.helpers({
    // with a nested template the data context (this) becomes a single product
    localPrice: function() {
        var currency = Session.get('currency');
        return fx.convert(this.productPrice()).from("USD").to(currency);
    }
)};
```

You might also want to have a default currency conversion and initialize the `currency` session variable in the template's onCreated handler.

Answer (score 0):

getEXR must return a boolean.
It's not like in Javascript, blaze don't evaluate this. You have to do en helper wich return a boolean

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned in my Comment you should probably follow the getting started tutorial but the key components here are that you're going to have to

1. Make sure the data you need is published from the server to the client
2. You're subscribing to the publication when this template is created
3. Use the template events
4. You'll probably want to set a reactive var or Session var when that select box changes and then in your helper change the value based on that reactive data source.
5. use a template fragment inside the #each and attach the helper to that (easily giving you access to the current product in your helper)